# Error in python showing : Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite

I cant to figure out what I am missing in this code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testing')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE testing (Name TEXT, Tutorial TEXT, Datetime Text, Duration TEXT)')

url='source.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url,sep=",") # use sep="," for coma separation. 
print(data)
 
cur.execute('INSERT INTO testing (Name, Tutorial, Datetime, Duration) VALUES (?, ?, ? ,? )',
            (data['Name'], data['Tutorial'], data['Datetime'], data['Duration'] ))

conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are passing in a a pandas `Series` object instead of a list of tuples as parameter. `cursor.execute` expects a list of tuples as parameter.
You have to first convert the data frame into a list of tuples. You can use the `itertuples` function:

```
data_tuples = list(data.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
cur.execute('INSERT INTO testing (Name, Tutorial, Datetime, Duration) VALUES (?, ?, ? ,? )', data_tuples)
```

Or you can simply use the `DataFrame.to_sql()` function:

```
data.to_sql('testing', conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Pandas library to load the CSV file is overkill and the cause of your issue. [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) is part of the standard library and is better suited to your use case.

```
import csv
import sqlite3
import os

DB_FILE = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "db_filename.db")
CSV_FILE = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "source.csv")

con = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testing;")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE testing (Name TEXT, Tutorial TEXT, Datetime TEXT, Duration TEXT);")

with open(CSV_FILE,"r") as f:
    csv_data = csv.DictReader(f)
    for_db = [(r["Name"], r["Tutorial"], r["Datetime"], r["Duration"]) for r in csv_data]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO testing (Name, Tutorial, Datetime, Duration) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", for_db)
con.commit()
con.close()
```